# Horizontally align radio buttons using Struts 2

Tags: html, css, jsp, struts2

I'm using Struts 2 to build my form. i must to make a radio buttons display horizontally but with my code, they displayed vertically.
Here is my code :

```
<s:radio key="type" list="typeAboListe"></s:radio>

{ min-height: 20px; 
padding: 19px; 
margin-bottom: 20px; 
background-color: #f5f5f5; 
border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; 
-webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
-moz-border-radius: 4px; 
border-radius: 4px; 
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); 
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); 
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); }
```

Any solution please ?